# Capybara with Selenium Webdriver click_link does not work when link text has line break

Tags: selenium, cucumber, webdriver, capybara

I am using Selenium2 with Capybara 1.0.0, WebDriver and Cucumber 1.0.0 running on a Windows 7 workstation.

I have run into a problem with my Cucumber tests where certain links simply don't get clicked. We have several hundred scenarios and a handful fails on the click_link command. I discovered that these links have a line-break in the link text because the link text is wider than the area it occupies. The problem is happening on Firefox and IE (I have not checked any other browsers).

I found this information which seems to cover [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1020) topic: Apparently the WebDriver clicks on the center point of the rectangular space for the link. When the link text breaks so that only one word ends up on the second line the WebDriver will click outside the link.

I am about to try to implement the work-around they mention in the ticket (send an ENTER key stroke on the link) but that must be a temporary fix. Does anyone know of a better way to get around this problem? I would think a lot of people would run into to this problem, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, the work-around they specify does not seem to work for me. I am currently stuck until they release a fix. Has anyone been able to figure out a different work-around for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I finally got the work-around to work. Problem was sending the key 'enter', when it should have been 'return'.

For those of you using Capybara and Cucumber, this works:

```
When /^I click "(.*)"$/ do |linkText|
     link=find_link(linkText)
     link.native.send_keys([:return])
end
```

Comment: I was facing an issue in an unrelated manner and had tried everything else in past 2 to 4 hours and then I encountered this... And viola it fixed my issue.

My problem was that an element with javascript event assigned to it was not getting triggered with find("#id").click, dont know why that was, but this fixed it and I am to exhausted to figure out why this worked and nothing else... thanks a lot for sharing this solution :)

Comment: @whizcreed: I had the problem, that click/click_on performed between 1 and 3 clicks randomly. This works...